# For distinct primes $p,q$ show $\exists$ a primitive root $b$ of $q$ such that $\gcd(b,p)= 1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have two distinct primes $p$ and $q$ with $p<q$.

Let $b$ be a primitive root of $q$ so $ b^{\frac{q-1}{t}} \not\equiv 1$ (mod q) for all $t$ a prime factor of $q-1$.

**I need to prove $\exists$ a primitive root $b$ of $q$ such that $\gcd(b,p)= 1$**

Now I know that as $p$ is prime, $\gcd(b,p)$ can only be $1$ or $p$, and it is only $p$ if $b = a p$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.
But how do I prove this won't be the case, so the $gcd$ is   1.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b$ be a primitive root of unity mod $q$. Consider $b \equiv b+q \mod q$.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps?

Comment: Suppose $\gcd(b, p) \neq 1$, i.e., $p$ divides $b$. What can you say about whether $p$ divides $b+q$?

Comment: $p \nmid (b+q) $ as $p \nmid q$ as $p<q$ where $p,q$ are distinct primes. so does that mean I can take any primitive root $b$ of $q$ and it's $\gcd(b,p)$ = 1?

Comment: No, that means you take either $b$ or $b+q$, depending on whether $p \mid b$ or not. I'm assuming you don't need a reduced representative modulo $q$, since your problem doesn't specify; otherwise my solution doesn't work.

Comment: but then (b+q) isn't a primitive root, and I want so show there is always a primitive root such that b and p and coprime.

Comment: it's a primitive root because it's congruent to a primitive root.